# Rails how to pass a variable with Fetch

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, progress-bar, ruby-on-rails-6

How do you pass a variable with fetch in Rails? Here is the current workflow and why I'm trying to do that. This workflow is an intermediate step to creating a progress bar.

1. Click a link in the view which calls a controller action (books#index).
2. The controller then returns a js file.
3. The js file then uses fetch to call another controller action (application#percentage_done) passing it the worker id.
4. Application#percentage_done then uses the worker id to find the completion status of the worker and returns that data as a json.
5. The js file then prints the contents of the json to the consol.

I can use the js code below to successfully call the application#percentage_done action. However, it doesn't pass the worker id. Code obtained from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
fetch('/application/read_percentage_done')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

This is my attempt at using fetch to pass the worker id. But it gets a 422 error. This code was adapted from [Use fetch to pass variable in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61799078/use-fetch-to-pass-variable-in-rails)

```
async function postData(url = '', data = {}) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });
  return response.json();
}

postData('/application/percentage_done', { data: '<%= @worker_id %>' })
  .then(res=> { console.log(res) });
```

Here is the contents of the config/routes.rb file.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  require 'sidekiq/web'
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
  root "books#index"
  post "application/percentage_done" => "application#percentage_done"
  resources :books
end
```

Comment: Rails will require an authenticity token by default for any POST request. The token is typically included in a meta tag which can be added to your request. However I don't get why you don't just use GET here - you're just requesting information from the server. I would define the route as `GET /workers/:id/status`. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Comment: Thanks max! I got it working now. I created a workers controller with a status action. Then I put this in the routes `get '/workers/:id', to: 'workers#status'` and the following as the JS file.
`fetch('/workers/<%= @worker_id %>').then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: How do we mark questions as resolved?

Comment: you can answer your own question and accept if you have enough reputation.